# Sort multiple columns of Excel in VBA given the top-left and lowest-right cell

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I am trying to sort these three columns (**Sort By Col-2**) in excel using VBA.
Top-left (Row number and Column number e.g. 1,1) and lowest-right cell (Row number and Column number e.g. 9,3) are known.
Every cell contains the values of String type.

**Input:**

```
Col-1      Col-2    Col-3

P1         I1       XYZ 1 | XYZ 2 | XYZ 3
P8         I4       XYZ 26 | XYZ 27 | XYZ 28 | XYZ 29
P3         I2       XYZ 10 | XYZ 11 | XYZ 12
P6         I5       XYZ 19 | XYZ 20 | XYZ 21
P5         I2       XYZ 16 | XYZ17 | XYZ 18
P9         I1       XYZ 4 | XYZ 5 | XYZ 6
P7         I3       XYZ 22 | XYZ 23 | XYZ 24 | XYZ 25
P4         I2       XYZ 13 | XYZ14 | XYZ 15
P2         I2       XYZ 7 | XYZ 8 | XYZ 9
```

**Output:**

```
Col-1      Col-2    Col-3

P1         I1       XYZ 1 | XYZ 2 | XYZ 3
P9         I1       XYZ 4 | XYZ 5 | XYZ 6
P3         I2       XYZ 10 | XYZ 11 | XYZ 12
P5         I2       XYZ 16 | XYZ17 | XYZ 18
P4         I2       XYZ 13 | XYZ14 | XYZ 15
P2         I2       XYZ 7 | XYZ 8 | XYZ 9
P7         I3       XYZ 22 | XYZ 23 | XYZ 24 | XYZ 25
P8         I4       XYZ 26 | XYZ 27 | XYZ 28 | XYZ 29
P6         I5       XYZ 19 | XYZ 20 | XYZ 21
```

Macro recording gives me following code:

```
Sub SortingRecord()
'
' SortingRecord Macro
'

'
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet6").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet6").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1:B9"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet6").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:C9")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

The problem is that I am new to VBA and not able to understand the meaning of many terms used in this code. So how to decide which statements are really necessary to program the solution.

The code I am doing doesn't need the worksheet number as I am running the macro on particular sheet so how to use sort method?

Please try to help me solving this problem. I do not want to get the range by selecting the cells so also want to use the cell numbers as given in the problem to make the program dynamic( As there might be change in the number of rows and columns).

Comment: Maybe this can be of help to get you started: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution after going through many tutorials and hence posting here for reference of any one who needs help.

```
Sub testSort()
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet

lastRows = CurrentSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastCols = CurrentSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set sortA = CurrentSheet.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRows, lastCols))

CurrentSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
CurrentSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastRows, 2)), _
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With CurrentSheet.Sort
    .SetRange sortA
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

**Note:** Range to be sorted start from row=2 and column=1.